# The QRcode did not displayed at the screen

Tags: php

```
header("Content-Type: image/png");

require "vendor/autoload.php";

use Endroid\QrCode\QrCode;

$qrcode= new QrCode('HELLO, thanks for watching this');
echo $qrcode->writeString();
```

Comment: Post your PHP code

Comment: <?php
    header("Content-Type: image/png");
    
    require "vendor/autoload.php";
    
    use Endroid\QrCode\QrCode;
    

    
    
    
    $qrcode= new QrCode('HELLO, thanks for watching this');
    echo $qrcode->writeString();
    die();

Comment: Same code working fine for me! have you installed to all the packages from the composer?

Answer (score 0):

```
use Endroid\QrCode\ErrorCorrectionLevel;
use Endroid\QrCode\LabelAlignment;
use Endroid\QrCode\QrCode;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

// Create a basic QR code
$qrCode = new QrCode('Life is too short to be generating QR codes');
$qrCode->setSize(300);

// Set advanced options
$qrCode->setWriterByName('png');
$qrCode->setMargin(10);
$qrCode->setEncoding('UTF-8');
$qrCode->setErrorCorrectionLevel(ErrorCorrectionLevel::HIGH);
$qrCode->setForegroundColor(['r' => 0, 'g' => 0, 'b' => 0]);
$qrCode->setBackgroundColor(['r' => 255, 'g' => 255, 'b' => 255]);
$qrCode->setLabel('Scan the code', 16, __DIR__.'/../assets/fonts/noto_sans.otf', LabelAlignment::CENTER);
$qrCode->setLogoPath(__DIR__.'/../assets/images/symfony.png');
$qrCode->setLogoWidth(150);
$qrCode->setValidateResult(false);

// Directly output the QR code
header('Content-Type: '.$qrCode->getContentType());
echo $qrCode->writeString();

// Save it to a file
$qrCode->writeFile(__DIR__.'/qrcode.png');

// Create a response object
$response = new Response($qrCode->writeString(), Response::HTTP_OK, ['Content-Type' => $qrCode->getContentType()]);
```